# JSON error message not displayed in AMP amp-mustache <submit-error> form

Tags: flask, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have the following form in an AMP website to display an input for an email registration dialog:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="/amp-register-email" target="_top" id="emailForm" enctype="application/json">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required on="change:AMP.setState({emailState: {hasError: false}})">
        <div [hidden]="!emailState.hasError" hidden>
            Email incorrect.
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrieren">
        <div submitting>
          <template type="amp-mustache">
            <div class="spinner">X</div>Wait...
          </template>
        </div>
        <div submit-success>
          <template type="amp-mustache">
            Registration successful.
          </template>
        </div>
        <div submit-error>
            <template type="amp-mustache">
                Error: {{ errorMessage }}
            </template>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Now in the backend I got the following method in my flask backend:

```
@app.route('/amp-register-email', methods=['POST'])
def register_email():
    email = request.form.get("email", None)
    
    # Just for testing purpose I am always sending an error message
    response_dict = {"errorMessage": "Die eingegebene E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits registriert."}
    response = Response(response=json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype="application/json", status=406) # 406 not acceptable
    return response
```

However, this `errorMessage` is not displayed in the  part of the form. Instead I only see "Error:" and nothing afterwards.

How can I send a customized error message from the backend to the frontend and display it in an AMP website?

Comment: Could you please clarify wether this is plain old Jinja or is this some sort of frontend JS framework for your email registration dialog snippet?

Comment: Plain old standard html 5 but embedded in jinja, so yes. Good point jinja uese {{}} as well... how to solve this?

Comment: @Undesirable Okay, fixed it with `{% raw %}{{ errorMessage }}{% endraw %}`. If you want write an answer I can accept it so you will get the credit. If you want to.

Comment: Did some research on my end (since I'm not that well-rehearsed in AMP) - hope it helps in terms of another solution you could use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Jinja was interpreting your Mustache template variable (`{{ errorMessage }}`) as a Jinja variable - as both were using the same `{{ }}` delimiters.

As per your comment, you managed to fix this by using the [`Jinja {% raw %} tag`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping).

The other way which you could fix this would be to [redefine the delimiters that Mustache uses](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#custom-delimiters) (perhaps instead of using `{{ }}` for your mustache templating delimiters you could use `[[ ]]` instead).